# Twitter developer API access multiple accounts

Tags: twitter, twython, twitterapi-python

I applied for a Twitter Developer account on my personal Twitter account, let's call it `@personal` for this example. I have another account, which I'll call `@bot`. My personal account has access to the Twitter API, and Twython can access and tweet from my `@personal` account. I need to have Twython post on the `@bot` account. Did I apply for API access on the wrong account and need to reapply on the `@bot` account, or is there a way to get the keys and tokens for the `@bot` Twitter account?

I'm new to this, so any help would be appreciated. Thanks and have a good day!

Comment: Check this out: https://dev.to/stratospher/many-bot-accounts-using-1-twitter-developer-account-17ff It seems you can do it, there are some hoops to jump through though.

Comment: That worked, thanks so much for sharing! Missed that on my initial searches.

Comment: All good. Best wishes with your bot.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found a solution here, fairly simple to do: https://dev.to/stratospher/many-bot-accounts-using-1-twitter-developer-account-17ff